# flex, amfphp, PHPSESSID... is there an elegant way to put it all together?

Tags: php, flash, apache-flex, session, amfphp

I'm developing flex app, with amfphp backend. There's needed a way to check whether a user making request is logined. I try to do it with help of php sessions (BTW: maybe you'll advice a better way). As flash player do not pass PHPSESSID I have to pass it myself. The trouble here that I cannot controll post params dirrectly (as I'm working through `RemoteObject`). Is there a simple way to pass PHPSESSID?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just include a sessID=PHPSESSID parameter in your remoting calls. ugly, but works.

Comment: @MarcB, still it will not be interpreted as $_REQUEST['PHPSESSID']...

Comment: you can extract it and pass it to session_id() yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just request remote URL's with the session id as a request parameter and call `session_id();` before `session_start();` to set the session to the requested session.

E.g.:

```
<?php
session_id($_REQUEST['PHPSESSID']);
session_start();
```

To prevent hijacking of sessions I usually add some encryption to the `session_id` which is reversible and I use a non standard request parameter.